# SQL Server TEMP_DB_CONTENTION

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is TEMP_DB_CONTENTION ?

In our server there is table named **TEMP_DB_CONTENTION** and is occupying **190 GB** of space. what is the use of this table and can we delete it if not required?

Comment: Only you know what that table is. [Temp DB contention](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/how-to-identify-contention-in-tempdb/) is a situation, not a table. Perhaps someone wanted to collect statistics in a table to troubleshoot it and forgot to shut down the XE session?

Comment: You'll find the live XE sessions in SSMS, under Management > Extended Events

Answer (score 1):

This is a user table, not something created automatically by SQL Server. Since tempdb is recreated whenever SQL Server restarts, it seems the table have been created recently. Run:

```
SELECT create_date
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name = N'TEMP_DB_CONTENTION';
```

to ascertain when it was created. The name suggests it might be (or have been) used for performance or load testing.